# Clojure jdbc create compound primary key

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

Not quite finding what I need. I have a table that needs a compound primary key (postgresql), but not seeing how this is accomplished using `clojure.java.jdbc`.

I'm trying to get

```
CREATE TABLE a_b (
    f integer REFERENCES a,
    g integer REFERENCES b,
    PRIMARY KEY (f, g)
);
```

I have tried a variety of things, but the gist is somehow getting `:primary` and `:key` to replace `"PRIMARY KEY (a, b)"` below.

```
(j/create-table-ddl :a_b [[:f "integer REFERENCES a"]
                          [:g "integer REFERENCES b"]
                          [:id "PRIMARY KEY (a, b)"]]) ;<=== this line
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is easier to bypass the DSL and just pass a raw SQL string like so:

```
 (jdbc/db-do-commands raw-db-spec ["drop table if exists langs"
                                   "drop table if exists releases"])
```

This is especially true if using a feature that is uncommon or is particular to a specific DB.

Comment: Hmmm good point, although not terribly satisfying :-P  I'll be going with this, but you'd think that compound keys would be pretty common, especially in DBs with many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found the solution [here](http://peterstratton.com/posts-output/2017-01-28-postgres-and-clojure-using-clojure-java-jdbc/). The right way to do it is to substitute my `[:id "PRIMARY KEY (f, g)"]` with

```
["CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (f, g)"]
```

I'll leave the question in case anyone else has a similar pattern.